Misleading min-width and max-width of @media in scss
I am following this question to display 2 buttons horizontally and vertically based on Responsiveness of the Angular application.
Previous Question
.dialog-buttons-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;

  @media screen and (min-width: 660px) and (max-width: 680px) {
    gap: 20px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 681px) {
    gap: 5px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 682px) {
    gap: 20px;
  }
}

First when the screen size is above 680px, then the gap between the 2 buttons is coming as 20px and when it is between 660px and 680px, it is coming as 5px. The @media query is not firing and the gap is not getting created with 20px.
I want it to have a gap of 20px when it is horizontally aligned and to have a gap of 5px when it is vertically aligned.
What is wrong with my code?

CSS is cascading, it means that the lower the code is in the document, the more precedence it will have.  (max-width: 681px) is always true when (min-width: 660px) and (max-width: 680px) and (max-width: 681px) is lower in the document. That's why the gap is always 20px

We can use the short form of gap which is
/* gap: <row-gap> <column-gap> */
   gap: 5px 20px;

So that when it's horizontally aligned, row-gap gets applied else column-gap:


.dialog-buttons-content {
  display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
} 
<div class="dialog-buttons-content">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
</div>

<div class="dialog-buttons-content vertical">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
</div>



